# Type conversions to custom class - C++

Tags: c++, variables, type-conversion

I have a class of complex numbers, loaded the `+, -, *, /,=,!=` operators both with complex and double types on both ways but when I write the code `complex z = 1`, the compilers gives me an error saying that there are no variable conversion from `int` to `complex`. Although, it accepts the code

```
complex z;
z = 1;
```

and everything works fine. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

The line `complex z = 1` does [Copy Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). You'll need an appropriate constructor:

```
complex::complex(int i) // or double or whatever is convertible to int by
{                       // implicit conversion
    // your code
}
```

This is different than

```
complex z;
z = 1;
```

which is *assignment* (to a previously default constructed object) that requires an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

You may want add a constructor which accepts a `double`:

```
class complex
{
public:
    complex(double d) : _real(d), _imag(0) { }
    ...
};
```

Be careful, though: this will make it possibly to pass an `int` wherever a `complex` is expected, because your constructor will perform an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an appropriate constructor.

```
class complex {
public:
    complex(double x) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that takes a `double`.

```
class complex
{
public:
    complex( double d );
};
```